# "Unexpected token =" when upload on Azure

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I'm facing a problem who I never has before.
I'm working on a chat bot powered by Microsoft Bot Framework, so I've already upload my project to azure few week ago and everything work fine.

Today I've upload a new update of my project, this version work perfectly on my computer. But when I upload to Azure, log throw me this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:656:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
Wed Oct 16 2019 08:25:08 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time): Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
```

This error are throwed by " userCourses = {} " Line 2 :

```
class UserProfil {
userCourses = {}
constructor(login, firstname, lastname, lastaccess) {
    this.login = login;

    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.lastaccess = lastaccess;
}
}

module.exports.UserProfil = UserProfil
```

But it's seem to throw error at every character like "= ( {" so it's not this line in particularity...  this project are totally  work on my pc and worked day ago on AZure, so I really don't know what can make this big issue

Someone have already faced this?

Thank you ! :-)

EDIT : After search, I found my computer run Nodejs version 12 and this declaration are new in Nodejs 12, Azure probably run the last LTS version (10) this is why it's not working on it. I've installed the LTS version on my computer and the error throwed are the same like Azure :-)

Comment: Also, use `module.exports = {UserProfil}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla JavaScript, you can't define class properties like that. You'd have to do something more like:

```js
class UserProfil {
  constructor(login, firstname, lastname, lastaccess) {
      this.login = login;

      this.firstname = firstname;
      this.lastname = lastname;
      this.lastaccess = lastaccess;

      this.userCourses = {};
  }
}

module.exports.UserProfil = UserProfil
```

[More information on JavaScript classes here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_classes.asp)

---

I have no idea why that would work in your bot locally, unless there's some kind of compiling that's done locally that isn't done in Azure. But that definitely is not valid JavaScript and shouldn't work anywhere.

Comment: After search, It's a new declaration available in nodeJs 12, I've edited the post https://levelup.gitconnected.com/whats-new-in-node-12-e00111ffb83f

Comment: Wow. I had no idea about that! Azure web apps currently operate on Node 10, so be sure to develop around that, FYI.

Comment: It’s my first work on nodejs so I keep my old practice of Java so I ve init all variable like that without knowing that a new thing in nodejs aha your answer help me to understand that’s a new thing ! Aha thank you ! :-)

Comment: No problem! It can be tough switching languages. We should have our Java SDK out of preview sometime next year, FYI.

Comment: oh happy to know that ! :-)